# Drupal 7: entity field as single/multivalued based on content type

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

I have a 'gender' entity(taxonomy) field.

I want to use it as single valued for content type X and multi-valued for content type Z in Drupal 7?

Is there any other work around to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, no.

Take a look at project [Field instance cardinality](http://drupal.org/project/field_instance_cardinality) and an issue [#1029298](http://drupal.org/node/1029298).

> This currently only works with fields that use options widgets (ie select list or checkboxes), and only allows them to be overridden to be single-valued.

Theoretically, you can create field as multi-valued and limit cardinality for *content type X* programmatically.